# How is this Qt application resizing the buttons to fit?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on an ACR890 handheld smart card reader.  This device has Linux onboard and the SDK is Qt based.  There is a sample application supplied with the device, 'ACR890_Sample_Codes'.  In this application there is a UI called DialogWifi.ui, screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot taken from Qt Creator]

When the application is deployed, this same screen looks like this:

[image: Photograph taken of same display deployed and running on device]

I've included the UI and the files associated with this UI below, I don't see anything either in Qt Creator or the source code that explains how or where the buttons are rescaled to fit.

I've searched for resize policies, I don't see any, I've searched for font changes, none, I've also searched for geometry modifications, again none.

I would include or attached the files, but I can't see a way of pasting it in here or attaching and keeping the content readable.

On the form, the buttons are contained in a QGridControl.

Here is a snippet from the UI XML:

```
       <widget class="QWidget" name="gridLayoutWidget">
<property name="geometry">
 <rect>
  <x>10</x>
  <y>90</y>
  <width>1107</width>
  <height>128</height>
 </rect>
</property>
<layout class="QGridLayout" name="GridLayout">
 <property name="spacing">
  <number>0</number>
 </property>
 <item row="2" column="12">
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="PushButton39">
   <property name="cursor">
    <cursorShape>BlankCursor</cursorShape>
   </property>
   <property name="focusPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::StrongFocus</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>&quot;</string>
   </property>
```

So far in the constructor that is associated with the UI I've tried:

```
    qDebug() << qApp->style()->metaObject()->className();
```

Didn't help, just displays the class name "QStyleSheetStyle", I then tried:

```
    qDebug() << qApp->style()->metaObject();
```

That just displays an address:

```
   0x4b66e440
```

Then:

```
    qDebug() << qApp->style();
```

And this outputs:

```
    QStyleSheetStyle(0x1502c0)
```

Then I tried:

```
    qDebug() << ui->WidgetPassword->styleSheet();
```

This is the parent of the QGridControl object, the output:

```
    ""
```

And then a one of the pushbuttons:

```
    qDebug() << ui->PushButton1->styleSheet();
```

Also:

```
    ""
```

Comment: In short `QLayout` and its children.

Comment: @MarekR, please explain as I have copied this layout and pasted into another form and it doesn't replicate.

Comment: Please provide a minimal and complete code.

Comment: `QGridControl` manages positions of widgets it contains. Most probably it is inserted inside by Qt Designer. Now style also has impact on margins and so on, so on windows UI do not fit inside desired width, but on your device different style is used and layout is able to fit into a screen.

Comment: @RomhaKorev, not possible, that's exactly what I've tried to do.

Comment: @MarekR, I've tried to copy the entire content of this UI to another UI, but the new version doesn't replicate the behaviour.  I can't see anything in the original source that modifies the content of the QGridControl, but for some reason the original works and my copy doesn't.

Comment: There are two things which can change behavior of layout without explicit interaction with it: `QStyle` and `styleSheet`.

Comment: @MarekR, thank you, I've searched the control properties for stylesheets, there are none.

Comment: They can be set in many places. On a parent widgets or on `QApplication` (this has impact on all widgets).

Comment: @MarekR, I've just edited to include a snippet from the XML.

Comment: @MarekR, I've searched starting at the application and working down, I can't see anything.

Comment: print `qApp->style()->metaObject()->className()` on device should be something else then on Windows. I have no other clues.

Comment: @MarekR, thank you, I'll look into it later on....have to get out and do some work in the garden now whilst the weather is fantastic.

Comment: @MarekR, All that is displayed in the Application Output is "QStyleSheetStyle", I was expecting to see the styles ?

Comment: @MarekR, Post editing again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having compared the XML of the UI file with the original I found that the geometry (width) was different in the new version and this was the problem.  I changed this to match the original, now everything is ok!